# Git gets hanged for hours together when deploy on github pages

Tags: github

The size of my project is 876 MB which got pushed on my GitHub repo without any issues using code:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 2097152000
```

but, when I tried to deploy it on Github pages it hanged for hours together without any result. Even during deploy used the same code but no use. How to tackle out?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, instead of pushing one giant commit, try and push multiple smaller commits.

Try with one, for testing, and see if GitHub pages are correctly updated.
Then add a second one, and so on, up until you get the final expected state.